# Telnet over ipv4 proxy to ipv6 host

Tags: ipv6

I have a dante socks server which is configured to listen in an ipv4 IP and to have an ipv6 external IP.
I am trying to figure out how to verify if that really works.
I tried to use `curl` but if I type:

```
curl http://google.com --socs5 1.2.3.4:9000
```

I will get an error on date socks side because `google.com` resolves to an ipv4 address and dante says that it can't route IPv4 because it has no IPv4 address configured as an external one. Which is pretty much expected.

Then I found `-6` parameter for curl. It now resolves `google.com` to an IPv6 address but also now tries to resolve `1.2.3.4` to an IPv6 address which is wrong.

If I try to use explicitly IPv6 as an URL for curl I get an error:

```
curl 'http://[2a00:1450:400c:c03:0:0:0:8b]/' --socks5 1.2.3.4:9000
```

Also I tried to use proxychains with the telnet, but it seems that if i specify an IPv4 address as a proxy in proxychains:

```
socks5 1.2.3.4
```

It siply ignores that proxy and does a direct request if use IPv6 with telnet:

```
proxychains telnet 2a00:1450:400c:c03:0:0:0:8b 25
```

So how do I telnet to something with IPv6 address via a socks proxy on an IPv4 address?

Comment: How exactly did you configure dante?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Something like: `internal: 1.2.3.4 port=1080
external.protocol: ipv6
external: aaa:bbb:ccc:...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is one of numerous reasons why it is almost always better to send a hostname over SOCKS and let the SOCKS server resolve it to an IP address rather than resolving the IP address on the SOCKS client.

In the `curl` man page, I find mention of two different SOCKS5 options depending on which side you want to resolve the hostname. `--socks5` will resolve the hostname on the client, `--socks5-hostname` will resolve the hostname on the server. I recommend using the later. Other `SOCKS` clients may also need to be configured to do hostname resolution on the SOCKS server. For example I have found that Firefox will resolve hostnames on the client side by default, but it does have a configuration option to do it on the server instead.

Also the man page suggestions using `--proxy` rather than `--socks*` options. From my reading the correct syntax for your case would be `--proxy socks5h://192.0.2.4:9000/`

Comment: Sorry, misread your answer. Yes, now I have a problem with dante which it seems does not want to resolve domain to Ipv6.

Comment: @Glueon Which version of curl are you using? When I tested it on Ubuntu 14.04, the `-4` and `-6` arguments did not affect URLs which already used an IP address. They won't affect the actual URL to be requested either, since the lookup takes place on the SOCKS server. So the only case where `-4` or `-6` would make a difference is if the proxy URL happen to be specified using a hostname, in which case you only specify `-4` or `-6` if you want to force a specific protocol to be used between curl and SOCKS server.

Comment: @Glueon I didn't test `dante`. In my tests I used `curl` as the SOCKS client and `openssh` as the SOCKS server. The SOCKS server in `openssh` can resolve hostnames as both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Sorry. That was my fault. I messed up SNAT rules that's why it didn't work. Your solution works. Thank you.